# Librería pytesseract no se importa en visual studio code

Tags: python, pytesseract, tesseract

***Visual studio code*** no me esta importando correctamente la librería pytesseract. Recién empiezo con rpa en python, instalé desde el binario que esta en github para tesseract, luego utilicé la linea `pip install` en el cmd pero cuando coloco `import pytesseract` no se importa. También lo coloqué como variable de entorno dentro de path.

[image: Como ven tengo instalada la libreria]

[image: Esto es lo que arroja la sentencia import]

[image: Aca tengo instalado tesseract]

Comment: Por favor puedes poner la traza de error completa. Ahí aparecerá desde el archivo que se está tratando de importar el módulo, y podremos ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

Yo estoy en las mismas,
He encontrado esta solución que he seguido al dedillo. Obviamente esto no soluciona el problema de fondo pero por lo menos el código funciona.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x-BtaZDbQeo&ab_channel=TechieDude

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/380005)

Comment: Hola Carlos, bienvenido, y gracias por colaborar, la pregunta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, las respuestas como está, son consideradas de baja calidad, te sugiero que la edites, explicando como  se puede solucionar el problema, a fin de evitar recibir votos negativos, y/o que tu respuesta sea eliminada.